# Implement an Activity Indicator for TableView in Storyboard

Tags: ios, uitableview, spinner, storyboard, uiactivityindicatorview

I have an implementation file that load data from rss in the internet, parse the xml and populates rows of my TableView. I would like to show an activity indicator above my TableView till the entire table is populated.

My problem is that with Storyboard I cannot put the activity indicator above the table view, but only above a single cell. But in this case, if I compile, I obtain a lot of spinners, one per cell.
Any ideas on how to show only one spinner centered in my table view?

Thanks in advance,
yassa

Comment: delete rows in ur storyboard and let the table view populate itself...then add a Activity indicator in center of the table view...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I've found the solution: with storyboard use a ViewController (instead of a TableViewController) and put above a TableView and also an Activity Indicator, as follows:

[image]

I don't know if it's the best approach, but it worked for me!!!

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at https://github.com/jdg/MBProgressHUD:

> MBProgressHUD is an iPhone drop-in class that displays a translucent
>   HUD with a progress indicator and some optional labels while work is
>   being done in a background thread.

Using that implementation you might get your desired effect out-of-the-box.